# Does a subdomain to my home server increase hacker risk

Tags: internet-security, subdomain

I am thinking of adding a subdomain to my regular domain but having it go to my office network instead of my website.

Will this make it more likely (if even a little bit) that a hacker can find my network and attempt to break in?

Or am I better off just memorizing the ip address or changing my hosts file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes it only marginally more likely, but not worth worrying about - particularly if its not obvious.  Hackers will typically scan IP ranges and ports to break in - the only "increased threat" are if you have enemies who are looking specifically to target you, and they can guess (or find through resources available online) your subdomain.  Of-course, oft times this kind of information will leak through email headers and surfing habits anyway !

One thing to ensure (but it will almost certainly be a default) is that people can't do full zone transfers, ie dump your zone to see your subdomain.